# PHP code just prints on screen instead of running

Tags: php

For some reason I can't connect to database. Here's my code:

```
<?php

//only process form if $_POST isnt empty
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {

// Connect to MySQL
$mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'username', 'password',       'database' );

//Check connection
if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli-  >connect_error );
}   

//Insert form data
$sql = "INSERT INTO user ( Name, Username, Password, Email ) VALUES 
( '{mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Name'])}',
('{mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Lastname'])}',
('{mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Username'])}',
('{mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Password'])}' )
('{mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Email'])}' )";

//Print response from MySQL
if ( $insert ) {
echo "Success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_ID}";   



}else{  
die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
}

//Close our connection
$mysqli->close();
}

?>
```

Comment: why don't you use prepared statement in mysqli ?

Comment: When you say "PHP code just prints on screen instead of running" do you mean the browser displays your entire PHP file? If that's the case then you don't have PHP installed correctly on your server.

Comment: If that is your actual password in the code snippet you may want to [edit] it out. Also please clarify what you mean by `PHP code just prints on screen instead of running`; which PHP code are you referring to - the whole file or just a specific line?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you make a simple mistake and forget to escape something.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. You're not properly encrypting passwords here which exposes your users to severe risks.

Comment: Relax @tadman - I am pretty sure that the OP will use proper code once he is able to understand it. This is just a sample, isn't it? :)

Comment: Learning to do it properly the first time is extremely important. Mistakes like this have a way of worming their way into production, and once deployed, you might very well have your server hacked or end up in the [hall of shame](http://codecurmudgeon.com/wp/sql-injection-hall-of-shame/). This is too serious a problem to hand-wave away. If there's one thing I'm "pretty sure of" it's that this needs to be said frequently because if it's never mentioned, many people have no idea it's strictly necessary for public-facing code. Safety first, just like learning to ride a bike.

Answer (score 2):

## Warning: your code is susceptible to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/601524/5971390)!

Never use `$_POST[]` or *any user submitted data* ***directly*** in a `SQL Insert`.

Use [Prepared Statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead!

---

#### Regarding the code just prints on the screen:

If the PHP Code is printing on to the screen instead of being interpreted by the server; first make sure that the PHP file is using a valid PHP extension such as `.php` and not just `.html`

Also make sure that the php module is installed for your web server (this would be different instructions for IIS then for Apache).

---

Also your code is missing the actual [`query`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) itself which is done using the following code:

```
$insert = $mysqli->query($sql) // do the insert
```

Then the rest of your code will start to function:

```
if ( $insert ) {
    echo "Success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_ID}";   
}else{  
    die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Without the `$mysqli->query($sql)` your hitting the `else` and `die()`

See [`query`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for more info.

Comment: `echo "Success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_ID}";` is exactly the same thing as `echo "Success! Row ID: ".$mysqli->insert_ID;` so it is just a matter of preference. The first one is also fine without the braces because it is not interpolated - it is needed when using array subscript notation, though.

Answer (score 1):

The sql should be executed to return a result `$insert`

Example: `$insert = $mysqli->query($sql)`

(And, as mentioned it's much safer to use prepared statements.)

Answer (score 0):

well, you wrote

```
if ( $insert ) {
echo "Success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_ID}";
```

That echoes exactly what is between the subsequent quotation marks (as a string)...

Answer (score 0):

The script will keep hitting the `die` statement because $insert hasn't been set. So you are right: it just prints to the screen.

When you copied and pasted the code from "The Internet" you forgot one line - as Philip pointed out:

```
$insert = $mysqli->query($sql)
```

Without it, the only thing that your script would do is create a connection and close it again - or, most likely: not even managing to close it because it would die before it reached that line. :)

The line you forgot is supposed to be inserted just after the $sql string but before the conditional using $insert.